# HTML Email Images working fine in Outlook but not in Outlook.com

Tags: php, html, outlook, html-email

I am using PHP to send a HTML newsletter email and I am having problems with the images in the email. In Outlook 2013 the images display perfectly fine but in Outlook.com some of the images do not display.

In the email there are two images: one is the logo and the other is the profile picture of the user. The URL for the logo is `http://70.39.151.44/~ramsay6/leadsheet/resources/leadsheet_logo.png` and it does not work.

The funny part is when the profile picture URL is `http://cdn.icons8.com/storage/iOS7/PNG/50/Users/user_male-50.png` (remote site) the picture displays, but when the URL is `http://70.39.151.44/~ramsay6/leadsheet/accountimg/1-ramsay.png` it does not display.

Outlook.com uses a proxy to access the pictures. Could the URL of my website be causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it! Webmail clients have tough security restrictions- that's why they don't allow linked CSS sheets or JS. It's also why GMail strips your `<style>` tag.

Looks like you need to host your images from a registered domain or else Outlook.com finds them risky and ignores them.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess Outlook.com doesn't like my domain.